# macro environment variables not able to access in python

Tags: python-2.7, macros, global-variables, environment, nagios

in perl, reference the environment variables with:

```
print "$ENV{NAGIOS_HOSTNAME}\n";
```

In bash, reference the environment variables with:

```
echo $NAGIOS_HOSTNAME
```

i'm trying to access the environment variables using `os.environ['NAGIOS_HOSTNAME']`

Below is the error

host_nagio=os.environ['NAGIOS_HOSTGROUPNAME']

```
` Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Read_nagios_parm.py", line 6, in <module>
    host_nagio= os.environ['NAGIOS_HOSTGROUPNAME']
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 23, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'NAGIOS_HOSTGROUPNAME'`
```

How can i access the marco environment variables of nagios using python.

This seems to be a simple error in which i need to export.

Answer (score 0):

From [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.environ):

> `os.environ`
>
> A mapping object [...]

```
os.environ['NAGIOS_HOSTGROUPNAME']
```

Comment: Then that environment variable doesn't exist.

Comment: `echo $NAGIOS_HOSTGROUPNAME

root@opsview:/usr/local/nagios/libexec/notifications#`     The output of echo $NAGIOS_HOSTGROUPNAME is giving blank data

Comment: That doesn't prove that the environment variable exists, only that the shell variable exists.

Comment: Sorry , how can i access this shell variable in python ?

Comment: You can't, it only exists in the shell. It needs to be exported to the environment.